# Fatal: Heroku repository does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I renamed my Heroku app from their goofy name to something more reasonable. I never imagined that it would cause me trouble here. just now I tried the following

```
git remote -v

heroku  http://appname.herokuapp.com (fetch)
heroku  http://appname.herokuapp.com (push)
origin  git@github.com:MyAccount/games.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:MyAccount/games.git (push)
```

I thought I had it won there. but then I tried

```
git push heroku master
```

and then i got this message

```
fatal: repository 'http://appname.herokuapp.com/' not found
```

I don't understand why it won't push

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change your heroku remote to match the new name for your app.

Do on the command line

- `git remote remove heroku`
- `git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:YOUR_APP_NAME.git`

Let me know if that doesn't fix it

Comment: I assumed you meant git remote. Anyways it looks like it worked. I followed those steps almost perfectly before, but instead of git@heroku.com I pasted the link to my app. Thanks a lot, that helped